# How to push rest-api data to useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to push the data to the hook on click so it doesn't get overwritten, but on click it overwrites the data in the hook.
I used `let array` for console.log, and it was working, but with hook data is overwriten, when I click on next item

```
    let getDataCategory = async (event) => {
        let id = event.currentTarget.id;

        await fetch(`http://api.tmweb.com/category?filter[parent_id][in]=${id}&filter[type]=0`,{
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': token,
            },
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                    setCategorySub([...result.data])
            })
    }
```

Everything will be added if the checkbox is checked. And delete the data that is unchecked

Comment: `setCategorySub([...categorySub,...result.data])` ?

Comment: `setCategorySub((prev) => prev.concat(result.data || []))`

Comment: @BikasLin Anyway rewriting, i just want to take data + next data from another click

Comment: @Александр do you have something like `CodeSandbox`?

Comment: @BikasLin First comment and you, was right. I just mixed up the fetch requests